# XQuery: Updating nodes based on the updates made in the same query

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I like to manipulate an XML file using some queries. I want to add some attributes to the existing nodes if they don't possess it before or during the execution of the query.

for example:

```
   // if there is a price and the parents don't have 
   // the attribute named hasPrice then add it to them

   <products hasPrice='yes' >  
        <item hasPrice='yes'> 
            <price>100 </price> 
        </item>  
        <item hasPrice='yes'> 
            <price>100 </price> 
        </item>  
    </products>
```

I tried the following XQuery but it says `Duplicate attribute hasPrice`

```
declare function local:propagatePrice($x)
{
  copy $t := $x 
  modify (
    for $y in $t//price,
    $z in $y/ancestor::*   
    return if ($z/@hasPrice) then () 
    else (insert node (attribute { 'hasPrice' } {'yes'}) into $z)
  )
  return $t
};

let $db := doc('products.xq')
let $temp := local:propagatePrice($db)
return $temp
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure to understand what difficulty you found.  What you try to achieve is certainly possible with XQuery (or with XSLT, which is more convenient for transforming XML trees, especially for multiple transform passes).

In XQuery, you can manipulate some XML trees in memory, so if you have your "transform" logic in 2 functions, then you can "chain" them like this:

```
let $input  := <products> ... </products>
let $temp   := my:first-pass($input)
let $result := my:second-pass($temp)
return
   $result
```

or more succinctly:

```
my:second-pass(
   my:first-pass(
      <products> ... </products>))
```

Comment: Thank you, as I tried some queries I found that is possible, however I have a problem on updates made in the same query. I updated my question to ask for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can put checking of existence of `price` descendant element and non-existence of `hasPrice` attribute in `where` clause instead :

```
declare function local:propagatePrice($x)
{
  copy $t := $x 
  modify (
    for $z in $t//*
    where not($z/@hasPrice) and $z//price
    return (insert node (attribute { 'hasPrice' } {'yes'}) into $z)
  )
  return $t
};
```

Main problem I see in your XQuery is, that `$y/ancestor::*` may return same element for different `$y` because they can share the same ancestor element. Besides not being efficient, the error message you got maybe related to this fact; *maybe* `if ($z/@hasPrice)` evaluated against a 'cached' value or something, so that `insert` statement end up executed multiple times on the same ancestor element.

Comment: Yes I can do that in other ways, but my aim from that example was to know how an update query executes! As you pointed I don't get how it throw that exception (Duplication) while I explicitly said it to not insert a attribute when there is one!?

Comment: Think of this process : 1. `<products>` doesn't have attribute `hasPrice` initially. 2. `hasPrice` added to `<products>` in the first iteration 3. In the next iteration, `<products>` get evaluated again, but still recognized as doesn't have `hasPrice`. This is what I tried to explain as probably the `if()` statement evaluated against initial state of `<products>` -cached, result of previous `insert` statement is not recognized-.

Comment: yes I got what you mean, but is it a correct way for updating in an standard XQuery? Is it a bug in the implementation of the engine?

Comment: That seems *by design* instead of bug, it is happen to be documented here : http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_Update#Concepts

Comment: Thanks that documentation was very relevant!

Answer (score 1):

Now the question is different then.  It is about XQuery Update (which is a standard extension to XQuery, so usually if you don't mention it, we will not assume you use it).

The way an update works in XQuery Update it different than with a language like SQL, or in any language with "direct side effects".  In XQuery Update, evaluating a query does something extra, besides computing the return value of the XQuery expression.  It also computes a "hidden result", the **pending update list**.

Every time an update instruction is evaluated (like `insert node`), the corresponding change is recorded in something like a log.  Only after the entire query has been evaluated, then all the changes are played at once.

The main effect for a developer, is that you cannot see a change made in another part of the query.  All *read operations* will always see the world as it was at the beginning of the evaluation.

This is different than SQL for instance, but it is very well suited for a functional language.  IMHO it is also more aligned with the concept of ACID transactions in databases.  So it might look surprising in some cases, but when you know how it works, it is easy: in your test condition, it can never see the new attributes created in the same query at all.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, you say read operations read from the same input source at the beginning, while the write operations incrementally change the output source? Could the write operations not check any inconsistency and just do their job?

Comment: The changes are applied all at once, that's the processing model for XQuery Update (without entering details here, that is a property that allows to optimize and "parallelize" XQuery code, even with updates, by defining them as non-side-effect updates.) That is "their job": be applied at once, and throw an error for inconsistencies (what else could they do?, create non well formed XML?, silently chose on your behalf what node to ignore, based on no logic?...)

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that the definition of [upd:applyUpdates](http://w3.org/TR/xquery-update-10/#id-upd-apply-updates) can help you understand a bit deeper how updates are applied.